# Set the `nth-from-last-child` color

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector that can select the `nth-child`, but counting from the last element?

I want to set the color of the 2nd to last element as red, but the number of `<p>` elements is variable.

Example:

```
<div>
  <p>Hi</p>
  <p>Hi</p>
  <p>Hi</p>
  <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be [`p:nth-last-child(2)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo), rather than `p:nth-from-last-child(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [`nth-last-child(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-last-child). It is the same thing as `nth-child`, but it is starting from the bottom of the list of items instead of the top.

From MDN:

> The :nth-last-child CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings after it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5YFJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
div > p:nth-last-child(2) {color: red}
```

It starts counting backwards from the last `p`, so `div > p:nth-last-child(3)` would set the colour of the 3rd last `p` tag.